# Dlib face detection from low brightness image

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I want to detect face from image with low brightness. I'm using dlib for detecting the face from image. But the dlib detector is detecting  no face at all. I've the following code to detect faces from image.

```
detector=dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
faces=detector(image)
```

when i try to print the length of the faces it displays zero.
Can anybody help me, what shall I do? Is there other way to detect images from low brightness images? thanks.

Comment: did you try histogram equalization? cv::equalizeHist for example.

Comment: @Micka can you give me some hint how can I do that?

Comment: cv::equalizeHist in C++

Comment: you can also try local contrast adaptive histogram equalization, which is a variation of histogram localization but applied locally for small sections of the image across the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dlib face detector is a very precise one. But as a cost it has low recall, especially when images are bad and/or faces are small.
Try another face detector, like
Seeta https://github.com/seetaface/SeetaFaceEngine
Pico https://github.com/nenadmarkus/pico
or OpenCV
Those may provide detections. But false detections as well.